# Kentico - update a record in a form table

Tags: kentico

I have a form table in Kentico which storing initial input records.  How can the end-user in the UI (and not kentico admin), update a record?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **Edit data** permissions for the **Forms** module for the user role you what to grant the permission to:

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-users/configuring-permissions

Comment: The option you offered isn't exactly for the question I was asking.  Explanation; I have an input form on a website which takes in values form the outside end-user (the UI).  So once those input values have been stored via a Form data table, how does the end-user (in the UI) update there current record values? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the form directly after submission, there is a setting on the form for what to do after submitting, just choose continue editing.

If you want the user to select a submission then edit it, you are going to have to probably display the list of all submissions using a repeater with a link to a page with a query string value for the ID of the row to edit. Then on a page pull that querystring value and probably have to [use the API](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/working-with-form-data-using-the-api) to update the record, or modify the On-Line form web part.  Doing this will allow any user to edit any submission tho, unless you have a way to filter the ones they can view to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you clone and modify existing *biz form web part*: `~/CMSWebParts/BizForms/bizform.ascx`.
If you provide [ItemID](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/10_0/api/html/P_CMS_OnlineForms_Web_UI_BizForm_ItemID.htm) it will load the appropriate record (this functionality already exists). For example

```
<cms:BizForm ID="viewBiz" runat="server" IsLiveSite="true" ItemID="1" /> .
```

it will load 1st row from your form table. So just clone and modify it and make it work with a query string and you good to go.

P.S. The better way is make it work with GUID instead of itemID, this way you dont need to check if a user record belong to him or her